# Tedious - NodeJs Script Not returning Resutls

Tags: sql-server, node.js, tedious

I have written below nodejs scrript for getting the result from mssql using tedious -

```
let request = new Request("[XXXX].[YYY].[ZZZ_GetMyParticipatedZZZs]", (err, rowCount) => {
console.log('inside exe')
 if (err) {
   console.log(err)
 } else {
  console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
  return res.status(200).json(response)
 }
})
```

I am getting result as `0 rows`, however when I mannually execute the stored procedure, I get below result -

[image]

I want to get the row count and the complete row (object).